# logback creates new file every prog restart

Tags: java, scala, logback

I have such logback.xmp conf:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" >

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%level] - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="application" level="DEBUG"/>

<logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ConnectionLogger" level="OFF"/> <!-- Won' log connections -->
<logger name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger" level="INFO"/> <!-- Will log all statements -->
<logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger" level="OFF"/> <!-- Won' log result sets -->

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

Every time I restart my prog it creates new  log file, but in my way I want to continue write logs into old one. So, what is the problem?

Comment: What version of logback are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `append` property.

> Append to or truncate the file? The default value for this variable is true, meaning that by default a FileAppender will append to an existing file and not truncate it.

For example:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%level] - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <append>true</append>
</appender>
```

However, since (according to the [javadoc](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.html) ... and the current version's [source code](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/src-html/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.html)) the `append` property defaults to `true`, it is unclear why you would need to do this<sup>1</sup>.

Note that setting `prudent` to `true` also sets `append` to `true`.

---

<sup>1 - Unless ... perhaps ... you are running into a Windows file locking issue?</sup>

Comment: doesn't help this

Comment: I think there is something else going on here.  Something that you have overlooked; e.g. something is deleting old log files on restart.  At any rate, I think we need a MCVE to help us understand what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Logback includes a feature which allows multiple jvms to log to the same log file. This feature can be enabled by setting “prudent” property of an FileAppender to true.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <!-- Support multiple-JVM writing to the same log file -->
         <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
```

RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender with the capability to rollover log files.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `<append>true</append>` in `<appender>` tag. It should be true by default, but let's check.
Documentation is [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

Comment: doesn't help this